# Is there any advantage for returning a value rather than setting global variables?

Tags: python, theory

I don't quite see the difference between returning a value with a function and just manipulating a global variable within the function. Most guides and books I've read seem to encourage the use of the former rather than the latter.

For example, here are two blocks of Python code that (from what I can tell) do the same thing:

```
someVariable = first_function(5)
def first_function (foo):
    bar = foo + 1
    return(bar)

anotherVariable = 0
second_function(5)
second_function (foo):
    global anotherVariable
    anotherVariable = foo + 1
```

Sure, the first example looks cleaner and more concise, but both get the same result; they obtain a variable with a value of 6. So is there a reason to use the first example over the second?

Comment: you should avoid polluting the global namespace as much as possible.

Comment: For a few lines of trivial code, it's hard to see the harm, but [_Global Variables Are Bad_](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: Global variables only have one instance, meaning recursion is impossible. Eg parsing an expression expr ::= expr op expr for a[0]+function(b+c)/5

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. But why would you want to declare a global variable and then change it in this way? If your goal is: 'Add 1 to a number x', then the first one is much better.
Also consider information hiding:

```
def addOne(foo):
    return (foo+1)
```

With this solution you as a programmer now exactly what the function does (but not how --> that's the principle of information hiding).

In the second example it's totally not clear and you have to first define a variable (with a specific name) and then execute the methode. I don't see the purpose of the second variant.

Answer (score 1):

First part has local code, which makes it **easier to understand**. If I cut the function and let you see it - you'll likely to understand what it does:

```
def add_one(foo):
    bar = foo + 1
    return(bar)
```

It is also **generic**, since I can apply it to a range of values, this keeps the code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
map(add_one, range(10))
```

Second part is **specific** to `anothervariable`. This creates an object-like behaviour, where a function affects a state variable (in this case `anothervariable`). Also, `anothervariable` is defined outside the function's scope, which makes it harder to read/understand.

When you encounter such code, you probably should have had a class instead, capturing the state of `anothervariable` and manipulating it. Or, you could have a generic function to do what you need without depending on a specific variable defined elsewhere.

If you wanted to achieve the same behaviour for another variable **you had to write the same code twice**, which defeats the purpose of having functions in the first place!

You would end up with:

```
assign_x_plus_1_to_anothervariable(foo):
    global anotherVariable
    anotherVariable = foo + 1

assign_x_plus_1_to_anothervariable2(foo):
    global anotherVariable2
    anotherVariable2 = foo + 1

assign_x_plus_1_to_anothervariable3(foo):
    global anotherVariable3
    anotherVariable3 = foo + 1
```

And so on...